# Screen video Recording in ios

Tags: ios

I want to record Uiview in ios .. I have tried but not getting clear Video.. screenshot is here : 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmwkr.png   please suggest .. it looks like there is problem in frame i am passing..

```
#import "screerecorder.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface screerecorder(Private)
- (void) writeVideoFrameAtTime:(CMTime)time;
@end
@implementation screerecorder
@synthesize currentScreen, frameRate, delegate;

- (void) initialize {
    // Initialization code
    self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
    self.currentScreen = nil;
    self.frameRate = 10.0f;     //10 frames per seconds
    _recording = false;
    videoWriter = nil;
    videoWriterInput = nil;
    avAdaptor = nil;
    startedAt = nil;
    bitmapData = NULL;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGContextRef) createBitmapContextOfSize:(CGSize) size {
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (size.width * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height);
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (bitmapData != NULL) {
        free(bitmapData);
    }
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        return NULL;
    }

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     size.width,
                                     size.height,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context,NO);
    if (context== NULL) {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}


//static int frameCount = 0;            //debugging
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSDate* start = [NSDate date];
    CGContextRef context = [self createBitmapContextOfSize:self.frame.size];

    //not sure why this is necessary...image renders upside-down and mirrored
   // CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, self.frame.size.height);
    //CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage* background = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cgImage];
//    CGImageRelease(cgImage);


    self.currentScreen = background;

    //debugging
    //if (frameCount < 40) {
    //      NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/frame_%d.png", frameCount];
    //      NSString* pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    //      [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.currentScreen) writeToFile: pngPath atomically: YES];
    //      frameCount++;
    //}

    //NOTE:  to record a scrollview while it is scrolling you need to implement your UIScrollViewDelegate such that it calls
    //       'setNeedsDisplay' on the ScreenCaptureView.
    if (_recording) {
        float millisElapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startedAt] * 1000.0;
        [self writeVideoFrameAtTime:CMTimeMake((int)millisElapsed, 1000)];
    }

    float processingSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
    float delayRemaining = (1.0 / self.frameRate) - processingSeconds;

    CGContextRelease(context);

    //redraw at the specified framerate
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:delayRemaining > 0.0 ? delayRemaining : 0.01];
}

- (void) cleanupWriter {
    avAdaptor = nil;

    videoWriterInput = nil;

    videoWriter = nil;

    startedAt = nil;

    if (bitmapData != NULL) {
        free(bitmapData);
        bitmapData = NULL;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self cleanupWriter];
}

- (NSURL*) tempFileURL {
    NSString* outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0], @"output.mp4"];
    NSURL* outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath]) {
        NSError* error;
        if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:outputPath error:&error] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"Could not delete old recording file at path:  %@", outputPath);
        }
    }

    return outputURL;
}

-(BOOL) setUpWriter {
    NSError* error = nil;
    videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[self tempFileURL] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    //Configure video
    NSDictionary* videoCompressionProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1024.0*1024.0], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                           nil ];

    NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                                   nil];

    videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] ;

    NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    NSDictionary* bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

    avAdaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes] ;

    //add input
    [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1000)];

    return YES;
}



- (void) completeRecordingSession {

    [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];

    // Wait for the video
    int status = videoWriter.status;
    while (status == AVAssetWriterStatusUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"Waiting...");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5f];
        status = videoWriter.status;
    }

    @synchronized(self) {
        BOOL success = [videoWriter finishWriting];
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"finishWriting returned NO");
        }

        [self cleanupWriter];

        id delegateObj = self.delegate;
        NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0], @"output.mp4"];
        NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];

        NSLog(@"Completed recording, file is stored at:  %@", outputURL);
        obj = [[ViewController alloc]init];
        [obj mergeAudioandvideo:outputURL];
      if ([delegateObj respondsToSelector:@selector(recordingFinished:)]) {
            [delegateObj performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(recordingFinished:) withObject:(success ? outputURL : nil) waitUntilDone:YES];
        }


    }


}



- (bool) startRecording {
    bool result = NO;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (! _recording) {
            result = [self setUpWriter];
            startedAt = [NSDate date];
            _recording = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

- (void) stopRecording {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (_recording) {
            _recording = false;
            [self completeRecordingSession];
        }
    }
}

-(void) writeVideoFrameAtTime:(CMTime)time {
    if (![videoWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {
        NSLog(@"Not ready for video data");
    }
    else {
        @synchronized (self) {
            UIImage* newFrame = self.currentScreen;
            CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
            CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateCopy([newFrame CGImage]);
            CFDataRef image = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage));

            int status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, avAdaptor.pixelBufferPool, &pixelBuffer);
            if(status != 0){
                //could not get a buffer from the pool
                NSLog(@"Error creating pixel buffer:  status=%d", status);
            }
            // set image data into pixel buffer
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
            uint8_t* destPixels = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
            CFDataGetBytes(image, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(image)), destPixels);  //XXX:  will work if the pixel buffer is contiguous and has the same bytesPerRow as the input data

            if(status == 0){
                BOOL success = [avAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:time];
                if (!success)
                    NSLog(@"Warning:  Unable to write buffer to video");
            }

            //clean up

            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
            CVPixelBufferRelease( pixelBuffer );        
            CFRelease(image);
            CGImageRelease(cgImage);
        }

    }

}
@end
```

Comment: Use https://developer.apple.com/reference/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder?language=objc. To record screens.

Comment: I used this but it produces crash ..

Comment: What is the crash??

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ReplayKit.framework/ReplayKit
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/42A55DB4-8A98-41D1-806A-CEBD7B30D170/DemoScreenREcording.app/DemoScreenREcording

Comment: Add the ReplayKit to the frameworks.

Comment: added .........

Comment: Still seeing the crash??

Comment: Thanku @New16 it works ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126013/discussion-between-shikha-kochar-and-new16).

Comment: can i add get Video From Replaykit and Embed Own Audio in it ..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library - [Glimpse](https://github.com/wess/Glimpse). It can record any UIView.

Comment: landscape/portrait doesn't matter here

Comment: yes .. iam using same but it Flip my  image and cover on full screen not giving me Proper video  ( not even in L:andscape mode ) Any idea ..

Comment: maybe problem is somewhere else, works for me without any problems.